# Select all the rows in R that have some attributes from other columns R

Tags: r

I want to search my dataset for those values that some attributes from multiple columns.

For that, I found that I can use grep like so:

```
df <- read.csv('example.csv', header = TRUE, sep='\t')

df[grep("region+druggable", df$locus_type=="region", df$drug_binary==1),]
```

But when I run this, my output is the different column names.
Why is this happening?

```
my dataframe is like this:
id    locus_type     drug_binary
1     pseudogene     1    
2     unknown        0
3     region         1
4     region         0
5     phenotype_only 1
6     region         1
...
```

So ideally, I would expect to get the 3rd and 6th row as a result of my query.

Comment: Hi Mixalis, please provide some minimal example data for your problem using dput(). Also make sure that you have looked into `?grep`, that you have understood what arguments you put into the function, and what the effects of these arguments are.

Comment: @tobiasegli_le done :)

Comment: Not really :) use `dput(df)`, that way we can copy/paste your data into our R-session

Comment: @tobiasegli_te the dataframe is 41000 rows and 60 columns. I don't think this is a good idea...

Comment: Then do it for a subset like `df[1:20, 1:10]`

Comment: @tobiasegli_te you get nothing different that what I have included in the description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125901/discussion-between-mixalis-and-tobiasegli-te).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes it can be helpful to use the sqldf library.

```
?sqldf
```

SQL select on data frames

Description

SQL select on data frames

this is how you could get the result you need:

```
# load the sqldf library
# if you get error "Error in library(sqldf) : there is no package called sqldf"
# you can install it simply by typing
# install.packages('sqldf')   <-- please notice the quotes!
library(sqldf)

# load your input dataframe
input.dataframe <- read.csv('/tmp/data.csv', stringsAsFactors = F)

# of course it's a data.frame
class(input.dataframe)

# express your query in SQL terms
sql_statement <- "select * from mydf where locus_type='region' and drug_binary=1"

# create a new data.frame as output of a select statement
# please notice how the "mydf" data.frame automagically becomes a valid sqlite table
output.dataframe <- sqldf(sql_statement)

# the output of a sqldf 'select' statement is a data.frame, too
class(output.dataframe)

# print your output df
output.dataframe

id locus_type drug_binary
 3     region           1
 6     region           1
```

Comment: I cannot understand why I'm getting an empty return. The return dataframe is empty.

Comment: the sql statement is correct? can you paste it here?

Comment: nevermind. Syntax error in the SQL statement. gotta have coffee.

Comment: ..most of the times it's because a simple syntax error :-)

Comment: It is a bit over the top to use sqldf for a simple subset.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use base R, the correct syntax is the following:

```
df[grepl("region|druggable",df$locus_type) & df$drug_binary==1,]
```

Which gives the following ouput:

```
  id locus_type drug_binary
3  3     region           1
6  6     region           1
```

Since you want to combine logic vectors you need to use `grepl` that has a logic output. 
Also I assumed you wanted to check for *locus type* equal to region or druggable, the correct logic for the regex in `grepl` is the one I used above.

Answer (score 1):

I like dplyr for its of readability

```
library(dplyr)

subdf <- filter(df, locus_type=="region", drug_binary==1)
```

Comment: @Natham Day `Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’`

Comment: Then you should try and install the package `dplyr`

Comment: @nathanday there is no need to use `df$`, all column names in `df` are available in the scope of `filter`.

Comment: totally right I should have made that edit, I just kept the questions syntax